# Can we bind the Eclipse content assistent hotkey `Ctrl+Space` to other keys

Tags: java, eclipse

For some reasons I want to bind Eclipse content assistent function to other hotkeys, as `Ctrl+Space` has been binded to other applications. How can we do that? I searched the Eclipse hotkeys list but cannot find it.

Comment: Preferences -> General > Keys "Content Assist"

Comment: @greg-449 Then I just cann't understand why people in SO said the key is `Ctrl+Space`. Your solution seems work, just wondering what is the difference.

Comment: The default key is Ctrl+Space. You can change from the default on that preference page.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can rebind most of the key bindings in Eclipse.  The preferences page mentioned in the comment is where those changes are made.  You have to pay attention to whether a key sequence is already bound to a different function.  You also have to be careful when binding multi-key key sequences, for if an initial sequence of the entire sequence is already bound to a function, your binding for a longer sequence will not work.

It's often helpful to sort the table by the key value itself, or to use the filter field to limit the entries that are shown.

You should also consider whether you should do this at all.  I add a lot of key bindings to specialized functions, but I leave the "commonly known" bindings alone. If you need to do this, do it carefully and with consideration for unintended consequences.

Comment: In my previous government job, Ctrl+Space locked Windows.  I think some commercial shops use Ctrl+Space for a similar function.